# Keying two armatures at the same time

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

I'd like to select and put keyframes on two armatures at the same time.
In maya I'd drag select,  and hit S to keyframe on both rigs.
In blender I'm currently having to exit one armature, enter the other, switch to pose mode and set a key.

Any animators out there that have solved this one?
Tried google searches but no luck so far

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top header menu > *Edit* > You need to disable the *Lock Object Modes* option and you'll be able to work on the 2 armatures, both in *Pose* mode.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, this works!

Thank you moonboots that was awesome.